# Keeping a Perl script from automatically terminating in terminal

Tags: unix, shell-script, perl

I'm trying to create a shortcut of sorts to a Perl script, by saving a terminal command which launches the script to a `.command` file. The script is interactive, and allows for the user to interface with it via the command line. However, when I launch the `.command` file, the script runs, then terminates after it finishes loading (the menu options are shown before `logout` and `[process completed]`).

Is there any way to circumvent the automatic logout and script termination?

Comment: If you launch a terminal with a script in it that reads from stdin, it should wait for input from the user, not terminate immediately. Can you give the contents of the "shortcut of sorts" that launches the terminal and perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the screen command?